# Good night for greeting

Tags: conversation

Is it appropriate to use Good night for saying hello?
I've heard that a person in a movie said good night for greeting, is it OK?

Answer (score 2):

Good evening is common as a greeting at night, a replacement for saying hello, while good night is usually reserved for parting, a replacement for good bye.

Comment: Than you, for your answer.